# How to balance the reducer when some key sets have too much values?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, reduce

As the data is not so balance, when clustered by key(must), some key sets have too much data, some have little. How can I balance in this situation?
I have look into InputSampler, will it work?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement custom hash partitioner, so that you can send keys with more frequency to one reducer and all other keys with less frequency to other reducer.

```
public static class AgePartitioner extends Partitioner<Text, Text> {

        @Override
        public int getPartition(Text key, Text value, int numReduceTasks) {




            //we have more keys in this range so we want to sent them to one reducer
            if(key >20 && key <=30){

                return 1 ;
            }
           else
                return 0;

        }
    }
```